# Lixf Color 1000 Alljoyn Onboardnig Error

Tags: alljoyn

I have been following a tutorial by Serge on how to onboard a lifx color 1000 bulb but for the life in me I cant seem to get past 'consumer.ConfigureWifiAsync()' function. I'm always getting 'Status1 = 36914 & status2 = 0'.

I have a TP-Link MR3420 router and I'm developing a windows 10 UWP app.

I also tried to onboard it using Iot explorer app but am getting an error too.

Please advise.

Comment: try to use the Alljoyn Dashboard app and see if you're still getting errors while onboarding https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.alljoyn.dashboard&hl=en

Comment: I tried the dashboard app...its working just fine...I've gone though the code but it seems that this app does not onboard the bulb

Comment: I was able to trace the issue. It happened to be in the xml file for onboarding, so I had to download a new one from allseen website and everything is working fine. :)

Comment: It's alright. I fifured out where I was going wrong a while back. I was using the wrong onboarding xml file. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's alright. I figured out where I was going wrong a while back. I was using the wrong Onboarding xml file. Thanks anyway